# Aspose Words : Font issue when trying to copy each node from source docx to destination docx

Tags: paragraph, aspose.words

I am trying to read each and every node in a source word document and then trying to merge two paragraph based on certain conditions in the newDocument object.

In that case I find that the font for both of it shows Times 12 but the size in the destination seems to be bigger and hence there occurs unnecessary page break for the same.

Attached the source code and the source and destination documents respectively for your reference.

In the Page no 2 of the destination document you can see a blank page coming because of the respective increase in the rendering of the fonts in the source and destination document.

Answer (score 0):

Aspose.Words mimics the same behavior as MS Word does. You are adding section breaks of type new page in your document. If the font size of document is changed, the position of section break may move to the next page (3rd page). In this case, the blank page will appear in output document.

We suggest you please use latest version of [Aspose.Words for Java 17.2.0](http://downloads.aspose.com/words/java) and replace section break *new page* with *continuous*. Hope this helps you. I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Comment: Hi Tahir. I am not changign the font size at all. I am copying the same font size in the source document to the destination document. I will upload the source code and the documents for you. You can check yourself. ANd I took the latest dll only and tetsing.

Comment: Source document [here](https://ufile.io/b882e) and the respective [output](https://ufile.io/7476a)..

Comment: I have copied the same source formatting but still the font looks larger than the source one. As you can observe it then creates page breaks. If it is word behaviour can you please help me out to find a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that formatting is applied on a few different levels. For example, let’s consider formatting of simple text. Text in documents is represented by Run element and a Run can only be a child of a Paragraph. You can apply formatting

1) to Run nodes by using **Character Styles** e.g. a *Glyph Style*

2) to the parent of those Run nodes i.e. a Paragraph node (*possibly via paragraph Styles*)

3) you can also apply direct formatting to **Run nodes** by using Run attributes (*Font*). In this case the Run will inherit formatting of Paragraph Style, a Glyph Style and then direct formatting.

There is no style in your input document. Please copy the text of input document into new empty document using MS Word and check the output. The output will not be same as input.

You are facing this behavior because there is no style in your input document . The styles of text are "RAUTRP+TimesNewRoman", "GUUSPV+TimesNewRoman,Italic". These styles should exist in your document to get the correct output.

If you want the correct font name in output document, please apply font formatting according to your requirement. After using the correct font name or style, the page break issue will be resolved.

Moreover, your document contains page break at the end of each section. We suggest you please remove the page break using following method.

```
private static void RemovePageBreaks(Document doc) {
    // Retrieve all paragraphs in the document.
    NodeCollection paragraphs = doc.getChildNodes(NodeType.PARAGRAPH, true);

    // Iterate through all paragraphs
    for (Paragraph para : (Iterable<Paragraph>) paragraphs) {
        {
            // Check all runs in the paragraph for page breaks and remove them.
            for (Run run : para.getRuns()) {
                if (run.getText().contains(ControlChar.PAGE_BREAK))
                    run.setText(run.getText().replace(ControlChar.PAGE_BREAK, ""));
            }
        }
    }
}
```